# AngularJS injection problemn on Android

Tags: android, angularjs

i have a problem with my hyprid angular. if i run the app on my android phone logcat say injection errors.

Thats my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="MyObjects">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0" />
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->

    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-snap/angular-snap.css" />
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="MyObjects">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- START: NAVBAR LEFT -->
    <snap-drawer class="">
      <div data-first-nav class=""></div>
    </snap-drawer>
    <!-- END: NAVBAR LEFT-->

    <!-- START: NAVBAR RIGHT -->
    <div snap-drawer="right">
        <div data-second-nav class=""></div>
    </div>
    <!-- START: NAVBAR RIGHT -->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <snap-content>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container title-bar">
                <button type="button" snap-toggle class="menu-left btn btn-default btn-lg">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="app-title">
                    <span>MyObjects</span>
                </div>
                <!-- TODO: TOGGLE SEARCH
                <button type="button" class="menu-right search btn btn-default btn-lg" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
                -->
                <button type="button" snap-toggle="right" class="menu-right cam btn btn-default btn-lg">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="">
                    <div data-search class=""></div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="view-container">
            <div class="container view-frame" data-ng-view=""></div>
        </div>
    </snap-content>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- Include AngularJS --> 
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Thats my app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyObjects', ['ngRoute']) 
.config(function ($routeProvider) {     
   $routeProvider       
     .when('/', {           
        templateUrl:'views/help.html'
      })        
      .otherwise({          
         redirectTo: '/objects'         
      });
 });
```

Thats the Problem...

in my chrome browser i have no errors but if i build the app via eclipse an run as android application the logcat say:

> 03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571): Uncaught Error:
>   [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyObjects due to:
>   03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571): Error: [$injector:nomod]
>   Module 'MyObjects' is not available! You either misspelled the module
>   name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you
>   specify the dependencies as the second argument. 03-23 20:01:40.666:
>   E/Web Console(13571):
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16-build.27+sha.edfca4c/$injector/nomod?p0=MyObjects
>   03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571):     at
>   file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
>   03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571):     at
>   file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1611:17
>   03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571):     at ensure
>   (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1535:38)
>   03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571):     at module
>   (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1609:14)
>   03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571):     at
>   file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3717:22
>   03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571):     at Array.forEach
>   (native) 03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571):     at forEach
>   (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:11)
>   03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571):     at loadModules
>   (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3711:5)
>   03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571):     at createInjector
>   (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3651:11)
>   03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571):     at
>   file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1379:20
>   03-23 20:01:40.666: E/Web Console(13571):
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16-build.27+sha.edfca4c/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyObjects&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'MyObjects'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16-build.27%2Bsha.edfca4c%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DMyObjects%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A78%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1611%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1535%3A38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1609%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3717%3A22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A323%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3711%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3651%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1379%3A20
>   at file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3745

please help my i dont now whats going on.

Comment: i think it is a problem with my bower files. Because i include angular.js via //ajax.googleapis.com/ and i have no angular modular error. But i have errors with other bower_components like this: _Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular-snap/angular-snap.js:1_

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ng-app reference from the DOM and bootstrapping Angular manually:

```
var kickStart = function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyObjects']);
};
document.addEventListener('deviceready', kickStart); //Phonegap
angular.element(document).ready(function() { //Browser
  kickStart();
});
```

Comment: No way with this solution. Checkup the comment above.